# Cannot get specific image from NYTimes website

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping metadata from the New York Times' website. I'm looking to gather three pieces of information:

- Headline
- Article URL
- Thumbnail image

I have been successful in gathering all three except in cases where the NYTimes homepage shows the article's image on the homepage. In that case, I've tried to capture that homepage thumbnail image, but have been unsuccessful. Here is my code so far:

```py
    for item in soup.select('.story-wrapper'):
        try:
            headline = item.find('h3').get_text()
            link = item.find('a')['href']
            image = item.select('.css-hdqqnp')
```

The css selector `.css-hdqqnp` references the class of the thumbnail image for article images that are displayed on the NYTimes homepage (as opposed to being just text).

How can I get the thumbnail image for an article if it's already displayed on the homepage, as opposed to being available only on the article page (which I've already successfully gathered)?

Comment: You mean get the `src` link of `<img class="css-hdqqnp">` from the homepage?

Comment: @user5305519 yes, however, only for each relevant article. Only a few of the articles have this image type, for the remainder I can collect their image with a nested `.select` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the HTML structure is

```
<div class="..." span="4">
    <div class="....">
        <section class="story-wrapper"> ... </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="..." span="6">
    <div class="....">
         <!-- ... your nested img-tag inside a div-tag with css class 'css-hdqqnp'  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

That is, the image is not inside the section-tag. Instead, it's inside the next sibling tag of the section's grandparent tag. Consequently, you could search for the image thumbnails like this:

```py
for item in soup.select('.story-wrapper'):
    headline = item.find('h3').get_text()
    link = item.find('a')['href']
    if (sibling := item.parent.parent.next_sibling) is not None:
        if (image := sibling.find("img")) is not None:
            image_url = image["src"]
```